# Can sound reflect from itself?

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection

If it is possible, what kind of conditions would be necessary? The case with electromagnetic waves could also be interesting, but I don't think that is possible.

Comment: At very high intensities both gases and the physical vacuum become non-linear for sound and electromagnetic waves, respectively. It takes really, really high intensities for em waves, though, but the first gamma-gamma colliders are under consideration by the high energy physics community. I don't know if any have been funded, yet, and if/when a facility will come online... but they are definitely on the drawing board.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the question a bit. Just from the terminological point of view. *Sound is a process, not an object.* E.g. could there be a sound creating such an obstacle that could reflect the sound etc.?

Comment: Do you mean "Can a sound wave reflect off of another sound wave?"  Or are you asking whether a wave can internally reflect with itself?  If the former, then yes (e.g., think shock waves, which can refract and even reflect off of one another), if the latter I am not sure what you mean...

Comment: Both interpretations are interesting to me. Can the sound compress the air in front of it so much, that it reflects back from the air, for example.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand wave physics, the only way to reflect a wave is to have a change in the medium they are travelling through. Two waves can have constructive or destructive interference however but to reflect each other isn't possible.

Comment: But couldn't a sound itself cause this change in the medium, in some kind of special conditions?

Comment: Sound waves can cause the medium to distort but they cannot change the intrinsic properties of it such as its density.

Comment: @Dean To a first approximation you are right. But sound itself is a wave propagation of pressure difference, which is necessarily accompanied by a change in density, however fleeting. Thus I posit, but I have no proof, that for high enough intensity, and low enough frequency, the change in density could be noticeable.

Comment: @Dean - Shock waves are an extreme type of sound waves and they definitely affect the medium through which they propagate.  However, one need not get to that extreme limit for a sound wave to affect the medium if one just increases the intensity of the source of the sound wave...

Comment: Okay I accept what your saying about pressure difference and density but I still dont think a sound wave can reflect off another sound wave. There's no precedent for sound waves and elastic collisions.